# Hijack top level redirection from within iframe to iframe redirection instead

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I have an integration problem where, from within an iframe, an application I do not own executes a top level redirection on my page.

I would like to stop this redirection and make it happen in the iframe instead, possibly by changing the iframe property `src`.

Would you know a way to do that?

I have read about `sandbox` iframe property which prevents redirection but it is not quite what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the iframe on the same origin?

Comment: If it is, you can just return false for all <a> elements.

Comment: @JNic it is not unfortunately

Comment: You can set `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` to block many things.